# How to edit a .py script inside Docker Quickstart Terminal?

Tags: bash, docker

I am using docker for windows 10, and I'm using the bash command to access the files in a container.
I localized the file I was searching for and I need to change a line in the code but I don't know how to access that script to edit it.
"cat" and "less" commands are not very useful.

Comment: The `vi` editor is probably available, although if you've never used `vi` before you may want to spend a little time with a tutorial.  You could also simply edit the files *outside* of the container using your favorite Windows editor and then build a new image with the updated files.

Comment: So there is not a command like "editor", the one used whenever you want to edit txt files? Do you recommend `vi`?

Comment: *I* recommend `vi` because I've been using it since forever and it is generally installed by default.  Something like `nano` may be easier to work with if you're just getting started, but would need to be installed.  I stand by my suggestion (echoed by DidierH) that editing the files *outside* of your container will probably be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

**docker cp**

Based on your description "docker cp" can be the most convenient way to do that. With this command you can copy the file from the container to your host, then modify the file and then copy back the file to the container.

There are also other ways:

**vi**

You can install vi and edit the file directly inside the container with vi.

**volumes**

If this is an operation that you need to do very often, you might want to relaunch the container and put the files that you are modifying in a volume.

I hope it helps,

Comment: since I'm inside the bash, docker doesn't recognize the command "docker cp ...". The terminal retrieves the message "bash: docker: command not found".
Do you have any idea about what should I do?

Comment: Go to your docker container by `docker exec it container_name bash` and  Just install `vi` or `nano` by `apt-get install vim or nano` if ubuntu/debian or `yum install vim or nano` if centos/rhel/fedora  than you can easily edit the files.

Comment: Docker cp should be executed outside of the container, on the host (Windows)